# PHP: require_once and inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, require-once

If I have:

```
require_once("bla.php");
class controller{.....}
```

If I then create in a different file `class control_A extends controller{...}`, do I need to again say `require_once("bla.php");`, or is it inherited?

What if the `require_once` is done inside the `class controller` definition?

Comment: It depends on what `bla.php` does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far we have two contradicting, but equally correct answers =) Let's see if I can't combine the two into a more specific total answer.

If any class requires any code or definitions in `bla.php`, then you will need to `include("bla.php")` at least one time in the entire run-time of your script. If your previous code:

```
require_once("bla.php");
class controller{.....}
```

is in the file `controller.php` then you can create `control_A` in the following way:

```
require_once("controller.php");
class control_A extends controller{...}
```

This is because the `require_once()` function essentially copies and pastes the contents of the file into the script at that line. Therefore the above will be seen equivalent to this:

```
/* INSERTED FROM controller.php */
/* INSERTED FROM bla.php */
necessary definitions for controller
/* END bla.php */
class controller{.....}
/* END controller.php */
class control_A extends controller{...}
```

As you can see, just by requiring `controller.php`, the necessary definitions for controller are now seen and parsed. What you can **not** do is omit the declaration of `controller`. This isn't just because you required `bla.php` while declaring it, but also you can't extend a class which hasn't yet been declared. So the following code:

```
class control_A extends controller{...}
```

will give you an error since controller hasn't been defined.

One thing to consider, however- since the class `controller` doesn't extend any other class, it should not have any external dependencies. There's a good chance that whatever you do in `bla.php` which must run before defining the class is either unnecessary or can be restructured. What exactly is `bla.php` doing that you need before defining `controller`?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're including the inherited class, it doesn't need requiring again.

I.e.

class1.php:

```
require_once("tools.php");
class class1 {

}
```

class2.php:

```
require_once("class1.php");
class class2 extends class1 {

}
```